# reactjs, redux and pagination

Tags: reactjs, pagination, redux

I have an api endpoint which gives an array of ingredients. Each ingredient has the following properties : id, name, measurementunit, density(kg/lt), cost/measurementunit. I have few thousands of ingredients and can keep increasing.

I am recieving a paginated api with variable page size from my backend server.

```
http://yoursite.com/api/ingredients?page=1&page_size=200
```

On client site how to organize my state shape w.r.t to `page` and `page_size` and `ingredients`.

On client side i want to display only 15-20 items per page. So how to ensure that the items are displayed properly with pagination.

Similarly i have few more like ingredients. Eg: recipes, users and more.

Will redux able to handle such large data.

Comment: I don't know if I understand the problem. What's wrong with design your state with fields `page`, `page_size` and `ingredients`? `ingredients` would contain just the ingredients being shown in that moment.

Comment: so for each page i have to store the ingredients in a seperate object inside state. DO you know any example on git.

Comment: how does the client know total number of pages.

Comment: You could include the `pages_count` in the ingredients response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ingredients response could be like this:

```
GET http://yoursite.com/api/ingredients?page=1&page_size=15

{
    pages_count: 50,
    page: 1, 
    ingredients: [
        //first 15 ingredients
    ]
}
```

Your initial application state would be:

```
{
    pages_count: 50,
    page: 1,
    page_size: 15,
    ingredients: [ 
        //first 15 ingredients
    ]
}
```

When user click `Page 2` button (or `Next Page`, or whatever), you dispatch an async action like this:

```
const changePage = (page) => (dispatch) => {
    doGet(`http://yoursite.com/api/ingredients?page=${page}&page_size=15`)
      .then(res => {
          dispatch(retrieveIngredients(res.ingredients, page));
      });
}
```

where `retrieveIngredients` is an action creator:

```
const retrieveIngredients = (ingredients, page) => {
    return {
        type: 'retrieve_ingredients',
        ingredients,
        page
    };
}
```

Then, the reducer that handles `retrieve_ingredients` action updates its state to:

```
{
    page: action.page,
    ingredients: action.ingredients
}
```

In your `IngredientsList` component (or something similar, I guess), you will just show the list `state.ingredients`. Also, your `PageSelector` will show from 1 to `state.pages_count` page buttons.